# Mongoose is not recreating the index collection is dropped

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know I should `removeAll` documents instead of dropping the collection. But why does mongoose not recreate the index after the collection is dropped?

I have a schema in which one of the fields has `unique:true` set.
The index is created when I start the server. But if i drop the collection, and new records come, the collection is recreated and records are inserted. BUT, the index for the unique field is not created again.

Why is it so? How do I ask it to recreate the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with *unique*. If you drop the index in mongodb, you have to restart the node.

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls
>   ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call
>   ensureIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on
>   the model when all the ensureIndex calls succeeded or when there was
>   an error. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior
>   be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant
>   performance impact.

Nevertheless, in development mode, you can recreate indexes in method (for example method tied to route or event) with:

```
(Mongodb > 3.0) db.collection.createIndex({})

(Mongodb < 3.0) db.collection.ensureIndex({})
```

With Mongoose it looks like this:

```
Model.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
  if (err) {
      return res.end(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for this comment. i was struggling with why Model.on('index') doesn't work. It turns out that it only gets called if ensureIndexes is called, but when dropped and recreated, the collection doesn't call this method.